5.1 surround pass through issues on Raspberry pi-5/8GB ram Model B
I have Sony HT-IV300 which capable to decode DD, DD+, eAC-3, DTS-5.1 & DTS-HD MA @ 192kHz/24 Bit(MAX). Connected with raspberry pi5/8GB RAM. When multi-channel content through VLC,DTS-5.1 passed through perfectly but in case of Dolby digital 5.1, I got LPCM 5.1 only. But when played with LibreELEC OS, Dolby digital 5.1 passed through perfectly but in case of DTS found only LPCM. Please suggest me any one that in where I was wrong.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
